# ¿hacer un Botón con efecto magnético, sin Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

**Busco hacer** un botón con `efecto magnético` como en este
link: [Clic aquí](https://phucbm.github.io/cursor-effects/magnetic-button/) usa "Jquery"

**Intente usar la función trigonométrica** `arcTan()` para sacar una constante "m" y "n" con los que "escalar" el `translate()` del botón, si no me entienden intentaré explicar mejor en el código que dejo:

**NOTA:** gráfica de la funciona atan();
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
let linkButton = document.querySelector(".link_magnetico");
let buttonMag = document.querySelector(".button_magnetico");
const lb = linkButton.getBoundingClientRect();

function magnetico(e){
//calculamos el movimiento relativo del boton junto al mause respecto de su contenedor(.box)
    x = e.pageX - lb.left - (lb.width/2);
    y = e.pageY - lb.top - (lb.height/2);
// sacamos las constantes m,n para retrasar el movimiento del boton, y asi no se mueva junto a el directamente.    
    m = 10*Math.atan(x); 
    n = 10*Math.atan(y);// el 10 es elegido por mi, para alargar el espacio de movimiento del boton
//
    if(-1.5<=x<= 1.5 & -1.5<=y<= 1.5){ // limitamos el calculo a ese rango y asi no tener calculo infinito innecesario.
    linkButton.style.transform = `translate(${m}px,${n}px)`;
    }else{
    linkButton.style.transform = `translate(0px,0px)`;
    };
}

linkButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", magnetico);
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link_magnetico {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    position: relative;
}
.button_magnetico {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
        <a class="link_magnetico" href="#"><div class="button_magnetico">Click me</div></a>
    </div>
```

Si ejecutaron jajaja sabrán lo torpe que salió mi animación.
No sé si hay otra función de cualquier tipo que me pueda dar un mejor efecto o en otro caso, tal vez estoy enfocando el problema de manera incorrecta. Graciass!!! cualquier sujerencia me ayudaría muchísimo... seguiré publicando mis avances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es muy complicado hacerlo directamente con Javascript, de hecho, debe poderse hacer, aunque supongo que involucraría temporizadores.

Sin embargo, con CSS tienes la opción de usar [transiciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition) para evitar que el cambio sea brusco. Revisa los comentarios tanto CSS como Javascript para ver los cambios y solo faltaría verificar coordenadas para evitar que el botón sobrepase los límites del contenedor.

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box');
let linkButton = document.querySelector(".link_magnetico");
let buttonMag = document.querySelector(".button_magnetico");
const lb = linkButton.getBoundingClientRect();

function magnetico(e) {
    // Calculamos el movimiento relativo del botón junto al mouse respecto de su contenedor(.box)
    x = e.pageX - lb.left - (lb.width/2);
    y = e.pageY - lb.top - (lb.height/2);

    // No es necesario retrasar
    m = x;
    n = y;
    // En todo caso, trata de evitar que se salga del contenedor
    if(-1.5<=x<= 1.5 & -1.5<=y<= 1.5) {
        linkButton.style.transform = `translate(${m}px,${n}px)`;
    }else{
        linkButton.style.transform = `translate(0px,0px)`;
    };
}

function noMagnetico() {
    // Restaurar cuando el cursor salga de la caja
    linkButton.style.transform = `translate(0px,0px)`;
}

linkButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Asignar eventos al contenedor, no a la ventana
    box.addEventListener("mousemove", magnetico);
    box.addEventListener('mouseout', noMagnetico);
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    /* Solo para ver los límites del contenedor */
    border: 1px #aaa dotted;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link_magnetico {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    position: relative;
    /* Evitar que el movimiento sea directo */
    transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
.button_magnetico {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <a class="link_magnetico" href="#"><div class="button_magnetico">Click me</div></a>
    </div>
```